# What is the simplest example of the tame representation type?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, modules, representation-theory

What is the simplest example of the tame representation type?

I tried to find simple example could help me to understand the tame representation type.

I know the definition of tame is like:

A finite dimensional algebra $A$ over algebraically closed field $K$ is of tame representation type if for any $d\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a finite number of A-K[T]-bimodules $M_1,...,M_n$ which are free of rank $d$ as a right K[T]-modules, such that as almost all indecomposable A-modules of dimension $d$ are of the form $M_i \otimes_{ K[T]}K[T]/(T-\lambda)$ for some $1\le i \le n,\ \lambda\in K$.

Comment: If $k$ has characteristic 2 then the group algebras $kC_2\times C_2$ and $kD_8$ are tame

Answer (score 1):

See this MO answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/5906/6427

In particular the path algebras that Mariano describes are very concrete.